# Do we know where Yirmiyahu HaNavi is buried?

Tags: history, cemetery-grave, egypt, jeremiah

When researching for another answer, I stumbled across an interesting source.

The [Midrash Aggada in Bamidbar 30:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Aggadah%2C_Numbers.30.15.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> והקב"ה הוכיחם על ידי ירמיה ע"ה אשר רגמו אותו בני ישראל במצרים וקברו אותו המצריים, מפני שהיו אוהבים אותו שהתפלל על הדגים התמנו חיים שהיו בנילוס והיו הורגים המצרים, ומלך אלכסנדרוס הוציא עצמותיו וקבר אותם באלכסנדרייה
>
> And Hashem rebuked them through Yirmiyahu (HaNavi) a"h, the children of Israel stoned him in Egypt and the Egyptians buried him because they loved him since he prayed about the man-killing fish in the Nile that had been killing the Egyptians, and King Alexander, took his bones and buried them in Alexandria.

Based on this, do we know where his burial place is? When I started searching the internet, there seems to be diverse opinions - why so much confusion?

There is a famous painting by [Luigi Mayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Mayer) entitled the *Tomb of Jeremiah* which [claims to be in Yerushalayim](http://eng.travelogues.gr/item.php?view=53671)?
[image]

And then there also exists some bizarre theories that he ended up in [Ireland](http://www.originofnations.org/books,%20papers/jeremiah_in_ireland.htm)???

So again:

1. Do we know where he is buried today? and
2. Why is there such confusion?

Comment: Interesting question. Note the confusion suits his book. Sefer Yirmiyahu is a very confused and conflicted book, reflecting conflicts both in the nation and in Yirmiyahu himself. Seems confusion about his burial is appropriate.

Comment: I hear yeh its an interesting one!

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95#פטירתו_וקבורתו

Comment: Thanks good find @IsraelReader! - so there's no firm conclusion then?

Comment: Surely if there is a proper tomb like in the painting it would be hard to miss?

Comment: The sources quoted in the Wiki article are all considered "mainstream", yet they all disagree on a historical "fact". I don't blame them. Yirmiyahu lived about 2,500 years ago. Things can get garbled over such a long period of time. Consider the strange case of Rabbi Yosef Chaim of Baghdad, known as the "Ben Ish Chai, who only passed away in 1909, and already has TWO gravesites, one in Baghdad, and on in Yerushalayim, on Har hazeisim. http://mobile.tora.ws/html/184-19.html and https://tinyurl.com/ke3nxryr

Comment: While not uncommon to find differing traditions about burial sites of famous people, it's possible that in Yirmiyahu's case, the explanation is that we know a lot about his life in general from his book but do not know what became of him at the end of his life. As to that, there are a number of ancient traditions - some say that he came to Babylon and died there, others that he remained in Egypt until he was stoned to death, and from here some say that Alexander the Great then took his body to be buried elsewhere, and naturally later traditions also rose eventually (hence Ireland...).

Comment: The mystery of the end of his life seems to be the key here.